# need a way to overwrite columns in 2 seperate pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, both have an identical emails column and each has a unique ID Column. My code used to create these looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\file.xlsx')
df['healthAssessment'] = df['ltv']*.01*df['Employment.Weight']*df['Income_Per_Year']/df['Debits_Per_Year'].astype(int)df['ltv']*.01*df['Employment.Weight']*df['Income_Per_Year']/df['Debits_Per_Year'].astype(int)
df0 = df.loc[df['receivedHealthEmail'].str.contains('No Email Sent')]

df2 = df0.loc[df['healthAssessment'] > 2.5]
df3 = df2.loc[df['Emails'].str.contains('@')]
print (df)
df4 = df
df1 = df3
receiver = df1['Emails'].astype(str)

receivers = receiver
df1['receivedHealthEmail'] = receiver
print (df1)
```

the first dataframe it produces looks roughly like this

```
Unique ID |             Emails | receivedHealthEmail| healthAssessment  
0         |  aaaaaaaaaa@aaaaaa |       No Email Sent|         2.443849  
1         |  bbbbbbbbbbbbb@bbb |       No Email Sent|         3.809817  
2         |  ccccccccccccc@ccc |       No Email Sent|         2.952871  
3         |  ddddddddddddd@ddd |       No Email Sent|         2.564398  
4         |  eeeeeeeeeee@eeeee |       No Email Sent|         3.315868  
...       |                ... |                 ...              ...  
3294      |  no email provided |       No Email Sent|         7.674677
```

the second data frame looks like this

```
Unique ID                 Emails            receivedHealthEmail|  healthAssessment 
1         |     bbbbbbbbbbbbb@bbb|             bbbbbbbbbbbbb@bbb|          3.809817 
2         |     cccccccccccccc@cc|             cccccccccccccc@cc|          2.952871
3         |     ddddddddddddd@ddd|             ddddddddddddd@ddd|          2.564398
4         |     eeeeeeeeeee@eeeee|             eeeeeeeeeee@eeeee|          3.315868
```

i need a way to overwrite the received emails tab in the first dataframe using the values from the second dataframe. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge the 2 dataframes based on UniqueID:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='UniqueID')
df.drop(columns=['receivedHealthEmail_x', 'healthAssessment_x', 'Emails_x'], inplace=True)
print(df)

   UniqueID           Emails_y receivedHealthEmail_y  healthAssessment_y
0         1  bbbbbbbbbbbbb@bbb     bbbbbbbbbbbbb@bbb            3.809817
1         2  cccccccccccccc@cc     cccccccccccccc@cc            2.952871
2         3  ddddddddddddd@ddd     ddddddddddddd@ddd            2.564398
3         4  eeeeeeeeeee@eeeee     eeeeeeeeeee@eeeee            3.315868
```